# How do you manage multiple developer environments with PhoneGap?

Tags: cordova

We are developing a PhoneGap application as a team. One teammate has a Linux machine and I have a Mac. Our entire project is a Git repository so, whenever we make changes to our project, we run

```
phonegap platform update android
```

and push those changes as well. This has created a problem as initially, my teammate built the first Android version. When I run phonegap run android with my device plugged in, I get an error. Here is the Terminal error:

```
nagarjun$ phonegap run android
[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] compiling Android...
   [error] An error occurred while building the android project.Error executing "ant clean -f /Users/nagarjun/Documents/PhoneGap/eduora/platforms/android/build.xml": 
BUILD FAILED
/Users/nagarjun/Documents/PhoneGap/eduora/platforms/android/build.xml:90: Cannot find /home/riyaz/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml imported from /Users/nagarjun/Documents/PhoneGap/eduora/platforms/android/build.xml

Total time: 1 second
```

Is this because his Android SDK was in a different location? How do you manage such differences in PhoneGap builds?

The build.xml line which produces that error had this line:

```
<import file="${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/build.xml" />
```

I presume that the ${sdk.dir} variable holds the root to HIS Android SDK. What is the best way to ensure that we can both build our projects ensure that platform differences don't break the development? Please help.

Comment: The local.properties file in platforms/android should be where the sdk.dir value is stored. If that is whats causing the problem (you probably have Riyz's copy of local.properties) then one solution would be to write a shell script to pull the project from git and replace that one file with a file for your environment. Then just use that shell script whenever you update your local copy and have Riyaz do the same.

Comment: That's quite the task. Also results in the file showing up as edited in Git for every push. Would that be right?

Comment: You're right. Do like Dawson is saying in his comment and ignore that the local.properties file as well. Then just make a note that anyone setting up a new local copy of the project will need to add their own local.properties file. (Note: All this is assuming the error is coming from because of that file to begin with)

Answer (score 2):

The way my team has worked with this issue is by only committing the WWW folder of the project.

All of the build, platform and plugin files should maintained separately to avoid build conflicts.

Each team member creates a project on their own system and then clones the git repo into their www folder.

Comment: Don't you find the need to directly edit any platform-specific files? Assuming that PhoneGap doesn't solve all problems, you may end up having to edit any file inside the Android platform. Is this the wrong way to do it? Should you force a way to always build all your features in the www folder?

Comment: You could use the .gitignore file to block only specific paths/files, probably most important would be /bin and /cordova in platforms/android. For our projects we only edit plugin files and just maintain those in separate repos.